# How to filter a a variable in a plugin's function?

Tags: plugins, filters

I am using a third party plugin in my project  , in that plugin there is a function like this

```
public static function get_form($EM_Event = false, $custom_form_id = false){
    //special lookup for multiple bookings
    if( is_object($custom_form_id) && get_class($custom_form_id) == 'EM_Multiple_Booking' ){ $custom_form_id = get_option('dbem_multiple_bookings_form'); }
    //make sure we don't need to get another form rather than the one already stored in this object
    $reload = (is_numeric($EM_Event) && $EM_Event != self::$event_id) || ( !empty($EM_Event->event_id) && $EM_Event->event_id != self::$event_id ) || ( empty($EM_Event) && $custom_form_id && $custom_form_id != self::$form_id );
    //get the right form
    if( empty(self::$form) || $reload ){
        global $wpdb;
        if(is_numeric($EM_Event)){ $EM_Event = em_get_event($EM_Event); }
        $custom_form_id = ( !empty($EM_Event->post_id) ) ? get_post_meta($EM_Event->post_id, '_custom_booking_form', true):$custom_form_id;
        $form_id = !empty($custom_form_id) && is_numeric($custom_form_id) ? $custom_form_id:get_option('em_booking_form_fields');
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM ".EM_META_TABLE." WHERE meta_key = 'booking-form' AND meta_id=%d", $form_id);
        $form_data_row = $wpdb->get_row($sql, ARRAY_A);
        if( empty($form_data_row) ){
            $form_data = self::get_form_template();
            self::$form_name = __('Default','em-pro');
        }else{
            $form_data = unserialize($form_data_row['meta_value']);
            self::$form_id = $form_data_row['meta_id'];
            self::$form_name = $form_data['name'];
        }
        self::$event_id = !empty($EM_Event) ? $EM_Event->event_id:false;
        self::$form = new EM_Form($form_data['form'], 'em_bookings_form');
        self::$form->form_required_error = get_option('em_booking_form_error_required');
    }
    return self::$form;
}
```

But I want to modify the variable **$form_id**  like this `$form_id = $form_id*5`

I can edit the plugin core file  . But I don't want to do it . How can I filter that variable from function.php file ?

Comment: no, you can't :) in that simple 4 lines, you can't...

Comment: Please post the real code. You current example is nonsense.

Comment: I have posted my original code , and the plugin I am using is wordpress event manger pro .